# interference of blackbody radiation with medium

Tags: electromagnetism, thermal-radiation

We know that radiation of blackbody is unpolarized. And also its phase are random. So I thought that electromagnetic waves from blackbody wouldn't be interfered. But what if there's a medium? For example, if light joins in brewster angle, reflected waves are polarized. So do we have to consider interference when we calculate the amount of power that is delivered via blackbody radiation with a medium?

edit)The power-receiving object is 'in' the medium.
edit)Am I allowed to simply integrate the power of the transmitted lights to calculate the total power that is delivered to object?
(Blackbody is not in the medium.) If I do, what is the evidence?

Comment: Do you mean from one medium to another? as with the sun( which follows a black body curve) and the atmosphere which refracts and reflects and absorbs? see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_spectrum_en.svg . You have to take it into account for the energy delivered.

Comment: In this model, the medium is ideal. It only reflects or refracts the light. The medium doesn't absorb the light.

Comment: for the sun earth interaction reflection is calld albedo, and does reduce the energy entering the system